# Getting a number out of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to get the id from the url.
So if the url is something like that: http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11

I should get the number 11 as an output.
But there is a different id on every site. And after that i will set the z-index with that.

I've already tried to write something

```
$.urlParam = function (name) {
var patt1 = new RegExp('[^17241]').exec(window.location.href);
return result[1] || 0;
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = result;}
```

But this doesn't work at all.
Does anyone know what to do?

So now it should change the z-index:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?');
var id = params[1].split('=')[1]; //params[1] will contain everything after ? 
console.log(id);
if(id == 11)
{
    $(“#one”).each(function() {
        $(this).css(“z-index“, 0);
    });

}

else if(id == 31)
{
    $(“#four”).each(function() {
        $(this).css(“z-index“, 0);
    });
}
```

And it should change the z-index of the divs

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<div class="contentwidth" id="chartdiv">
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <div id="one" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div id="two" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div id="three" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div id="four" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1 ">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Will not work if there are many params

Comment: So what would you do to get the id of the <a> ?https://jsfiddle.net/wz6bkdn2/1/

Comment: Why don't you just output the id value on the server side into the javascript?

Comment: @Perplexor I already tried to do it inside of c# because I have an if-else and i used scriptmanager. But  i couldn't do it.

Comment: Alrighty. Although I think that'd be your best choice, I'll add an answer with a possible client-side solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `split()`

```
var url = 'http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11'
var params = url.split('?');
var id=params[1].split('=')[1]; //params[1] will contain everything after ? 
console.log(id);
```

**EDIT**

To get the url inside the `var url` replace the first line with

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Comment: And how do I get the url inside the variable url?

Answer (score 3):

It's called query string

here is the function,

```
 function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }
```

and how you call

```
getParameterByName(name)
```

Above code is from here
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`:

```
alert(window.location.href.match(/\?id=(\d+)/i)[1]);
```

1. `\?`: Match `?`. need to escape by `\`
2. `id=`: Matches exact string `id=`
3. `\d+`: Matches any no. of digits
4. `()`: Grouping.
5. `i`: Case Insensitive match

Comment: But how do I do it when the url should get read from above?

Comment: @fusionchart_help You can use `window.location.href`. Check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as an actual number I would write a generic version

```
function getParamAsNumber(url, param) {
    param = param + '=';
    if (url.indexOf(param) !== -1) {
        return parseInt(url.substr(url.indexOf(param) + param.length));
    }
}
```

It converts to integer the string after param + '=' (in your case 'id=')

So you can do

```
getParamAsNumber(window.location.href, 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this method to obtain any parameter from the URL of the current window:

```
function obtainParameter(key) {
    var result=null, tmp;
    window.location.search //this attribute stores the string found after a ‘?’ in the URL, including the question mark.
        .substr(1) //removing question mark in position 0
        .split("&") //obtaining the pairs key=value
        .forEach(function (item) {
            tmp = item.split("="); // tmp[0] is the parameter name, tmp[1] is the value
            if (tmp[0] === key) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```

Having it, you only need to write:

```
var id=obtainParameter('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11";

url = url.split("=")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11';
var match = url.match(/id=(\d+)/)
if (match) {
    var id = match[1];
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the url inside the variable var?

Comment: Already @Zee has explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function: `string.split(separator,limit)`

```
 var str = "http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11";
 var res = str.split("=", 2);
 document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = res[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex for this small task.
You can use the function below to get your requirements :

```
function getvalue(murl,para)
{
   try
   {
        return (murl.split(para+"=")[1]).split("&")[0];
   }
catch(e)
   {
      return '';
   }
}
var murl = 'http://localhost:17241/Chart.aspx?id=11';
var id = getvalue(murl,'id');
```

It will not return anything when the GET parameter is not found.

In your case :

```
var id = getvalue(window.location.href,'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use this function for getting query string parameters with JS:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split('&');
  for(var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split('=');
    if(pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    };
  }:
  return(false);
};
```

Then you can get the value of `id` like this:

```
var yourID = getQueryVariable('id');
```